# Matching and forwarding fake e-mail to existing e-mail

Tags: email-server

To guarantee anonymity and protect privacy to users, I am required to set-up an e-mail server that does something like this:

1. Upload generated e-mails (sdf12@domain.com) and real e-mails (bob@company.com)
2. Receive e-mails from generated e-mails (sdf12@domain.com).
3. Send-emails to real e-mails (bob@company.com).

Thus: mails from sdf12@domain.com go to bob@company.com

How do I do this? Postfix? And how is this technique called? Is it "mail forwarding" or "e-mail relay"?

I have a lot of experience in devops and I am a software developer. But I am not really familiar with e-mail systems.

**Edit**: The whole point is that there will be a system in which the customer uploads raw, real e-mail addressed, that the system converts it to anonymized e-mail addresses, and that we in the organization can use only these anonymized e-mail addresses. This has the advantage that we can still use e-mail addresses everywhere, but that we will never see the real e-mail addresses nor possess them. We have to do this to comply with local legislation.

Comment: Sounds like [Mixminion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixminion). I have no idea if it is maintained or supported.

Comment: Did you mean to say that **replies** to mail from `sdf12@domain.com` go to `bob@company.com`?

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is called aliases or redirects and probably every decent e-mail server can do it. Let me describe a solution for **Exim** on Debian. We want to redirect mails to `local_part@clients.domain.com` to their real address.

To make the administration of aliases easier, let us put them in an SQL table (in this example on Postgres, server `localhost`, database `client_db`):

```
CREATE TABLE client_aliases (local_part VARCHAR(32) PRIMARY KEY, real_address VARCHAR(64));
```

It will contain the anonymous local part of the e-mail address and the real addresses of your clients. Then we need to add Postgres credentials to Exim's configuration. In order to do it add a file `/etc/exim4/conf.d/main/99_servers` with content:

```
hide psql_servers = localhost/client_db/exim_role/exim_password
```

where `exim_role` and `exim_password` are Postgres credentials for Exim. At the same time we need to correct the permissions on the config file generated by Debian, so we need to change a line in `/etc/exim/update-exim4.conf.conf`:

```
CFILEMODE='640'
```

Next we create an Exim router in file `/etc/exim4/conf.d/450_client-aliases` with content:

```
client_aliases:
    debug_print = "R: client_aliases for $local_part@$domain"
    driver = redirect
    domains = clients.domain.com
    data = ${lookup pgsql{SELECT real_address FROM client_aliases WHERE local_part='${sg{$local_part}{'}{''}}'}}
```

[Cf. [database lookups](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-file_and_database_lookups.html) and [redirect router](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_redirect_router.html)]

Now you just need to add some data to the table, regenerate Exim's configuration and you can start checking e-mail address resolution:

```
update-exim4.conf
exim4 -bt
```

**Edit:** Of course you need also to change other parts of Exim's default configuration, set up some ACLs so the redirects work only for certain IPs and sender addresses, check the SPF policy, so that the Exim server is authorized to send e-mails with envelope sender from your domain, etc. My point was to prove that setting up aliases from a DB table is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks! It is already helpful that I know it's called "aliasing" (makes sense, in hindsight). So, provided I setup a mailserver correctly etc, as long as I update and maintain a table in a DB, the mailserver can forward mail. Nice.

Comment: The DB can also be a plain file or **sqlite**. A database table is just easier to update.